# About Gotfocus and MouseClick event

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, mouseevent

I have added one combo box on form and written Got focus event for that as DroppedDown=True.
But when I click on the combobox first that gotfocus event get call and items list get pop up. But after that due to mouse up event that list again pop down so i cann't see the pop up list.
How to tackle this??
Can low level event or global hooks help in this case??

Comment: After reading it twice I'm still don't get what you want exactly. \So if it is urgent, spell it out. A little code would help.

Comment: @Henk
http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/774872/ComboBox_DroppedDown.html
you will understand my problem here...
This guy has same problem..

Comment: I have noticed this behavior in winform, wpf, with basic controls and third party.  If the drop-down is open you have to click twice.  It's like the first click is setting focus back to form.  So, this may be a flaw in .net but you may need much more work or low level hooks to make this work they way you want.  Maybe some crazy code on the form click if it's even fired.

Answer (score 0):

I shall suggest you not to handle `GotFocus` event.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
combobox.DroppedDown = true;
```

Comment: Please explain this answer

Comment: Prevent to popup dropdown (combobox.DroppedDown = true;) when combobox get focus by clicking